# YUM not installing php-pecl-memcached on CentOS 6.5 with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, memcached, centos6, yum, pecl

I'm having some trouble installing the Memcached (with a D) PHP extension using YUM on CentOS 6.5 with PHP 5.4. When I run `yum install php-pecl-memcached` I am presented with the following:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php54w-common-5.4.26-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I believe I understand the issue to be that the version of memcached in the YUM repo requires php-common-5.3 but I don't quite understand how to move beyond this issue or where to find a version compatible with my configuration.

Comment: Does a `yum update` first help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not.

Comment: The root cause of the problem here is that you are using PHP 5.4 from Webtatic repo and unfortunately they don't have memcached package out there at the moment. The php-pecl-memcached on CentOS 6.5 will only work with PHP 5.3 from default repository.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling `php54w-common` and then installing `php-pecl-memcached` should help to resolve the conflict:

```
yum remove php54w-common
yum install php-pecl-memcached
```

But, maybe you can use Software collections (available for CentOS) instead of that repo `php54w-common` comes from. There are both PHP 5.4 and 5.5:

- https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/php55/
- https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/php54/

but there are more PHP builds as well:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=php